# What is the type of `typeof x` in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

In typescript you can define a class like so:

```
class Sup {

    static member: any;
    static log() {
         console.log('sup');
    }
}
```

If you do the following:

```
let x = Sup;
```

Why is the type of x equal to `typeof Sup` (when I highlighted the type in vscode) and what does `typeof Sup` mean? Is this linked to the `typeof` operator?

Furthermore, how do you type something like `let y = Object.create(Sup)`?
Is this typed as `let y: typeof Sup = Object.create(Sup)`?

Comment: `typeof` returns a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof` has a different meaning in TypeScript's type space than in normal JS. It's an operator to get the type of something that exists in the value space.

```
let person = { name: 'bob', age: 26 }

type Person = typeof person // Person is { name: string, age: number }

// These are all equivalent
let personRef1: { name: string, age: number } = person
let personRef2: typeof person = person
let personRef3: Person = person
let personRef4 = person

// more examples
let secret = 'helloworld'
type Secret = typeof secret // string

let key = 123
type Key = typeof key // number

let add = (a: number, b: number) => a + b
type Add = typeof add // (a: number, b: number) => number
```

So, when you assign `SomeClass` to a variable, the variable's type will be `typeof SomeClass`. The only reason it's not simplified like the above examples is because there's no way to non-ambiguously simplify the type of a class; it stays as `typeof SomeClass` for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Ahh so I think I sort of get it, maybe I should instead use a type alias such as 
`type SupClass = typeof Sup` or even `type SupConstructor` or `type SupClone`? So I can give a bit more semantics to what it is?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `let x = Sup;` (or more precisely, inferred `typeof Sup`) means that variable `x` can hold `Sup` constructor function but not the instance itself:

```
class Sup { }

let x: typeof Sup;

x = Sup;       // ok
x = new Sup(); // invalid.
```